# argparse, is there a way to pass specific columns of a csv file

Tags: python, argparse

I have a csv file, I want to pass specific columns of it to the script using argparse. Is it possible to do that? Can you please show me how that would be done.
Here's an example
contents of test_file

```
id code address           city        zip 
1   232 123 main street   bahtina.    abc34
2   421 321 pagalkhana    frombehram. zila132
```

`python3 main.py -f test_file.csv -a [address column of test_file.csv] -c [city column of test_file] -z "zip of test_file`

Comment: The `argparse` just defines and parses those input arguments.  That looks like a straight forward use of the module, as described in its docs.  You own code has to take of reading the `csv`, and selecting the columns.  `pandas` is probably the simplest tool for this, though you could work with Python lists or `numpy` arrays.

Comment: your flags would be booleans to select those columns? For example, if -a is present, select the address column?

Comment: @hpaulj I know how to do that in pandas, what I was asking for was is it possible to pass a chunk of column data through argparse without sorting it in pandas.,

Comment: @josemz okay this makes sense so when I include those flags like - a that means it will automatically select those columns inside the script?

Comment: `python3 main.py -f test_file.csv -a address -c city`, would fetch three strings that could then be used in `pandas` code.  There's nothing in `argparse` to handle `csv` files directly.  I don't know what you mean by "chunk of column data".

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to use the flags to select specific columns of a file. If that's the case you might want to have a look at [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). With this tool you can do something like:

`csvcut -c address,city test_file.csv | csvlook`

If you really want to use argparse and your own script, here's some sample code:

```py
# CLI
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f')
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

# File handling
import pandas as pd

# Select include columns from arguments
usecols = []
if args.a: usecols.append('address')
if args.c: usecols.append('city')

# Read the file in the f argument with the specified columns.
df = pd.read_csv(args.f, usecols=usecols)
# Do something with df here
```